# Wrong filename when downloading file whose name contains double quote(") from Springboot server

Tags: spring-boot, browser, encode

The code for setting filename for the file to be downloaded :

```
String originalFileNameDecoded = URLDecoder.decode(originalFileName, "UTF-8");
URI uri = new URI(null, null, originalFileNameDecoded, null);
return ResponseEntity.ok()
       .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + uri.toASCIIString() + "\"")
        .contentLength(resource.contentLength())
        .contentType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .body(resource);
```

The reason why first decode the filename is because the **originalFileName** may contains URL encoded characters.

For files with regular names (only number and English letter), it works fine. However, when I try to download a file with name like **pic201;9050.814,3"731(copy).png** in the browser (chrome on linux), the filename becomes **pic201;9050.814,3_731(copy).png**.
I used to believe it is the browser behaviour, but I tried it in Edge and the same situation happened again.
So I wonder if there is something wrong with my code or something else happened.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://bugs.launchpad.net/mahara/+bug/1578512 Have you tried replacing `"` with `\"` when building the value of the `Content-Disposition` header?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Thanks for your comment. I tried your way by escaping double quote, but it didn't work and it becomes pic201;9050.814,3__731(copy).png which contains one more underscore.To be more precise, here is my code to replace the ```"```: ```String originalFileNameDecoded = URLDecoder.decode(originalFileName, "UTF-8").replace("\"", "\\\"");```